# UWP: How do I read lyrics from a local music file?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

The lyrics are nested in the music file, not downloaded from the internet. the `MusicProperties` does not have such attribute.

I have tried using `Id3` package to read it and that requires path to the file. However, in UWP there seems no way to access a file using path like `C:/Users/Seaky/Desktop/Music/SomeMusic.mp3` (at least not working for me as I get permission denied even with `broadFileSystemAccess`.).

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do that as `Mp3` accepts a Stream object in its constructor. Therefore, I am able to do this:

```
    public async Task<string> GetLyrics()
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Path);
        using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            using (var mp3 = new Mp3(stream.AsStream()))
            {
                var lyrics = mp3.GetTag(Id3TagFamily.Version2X).Lyrics;
                return lyrics.Count > 0 ? lyrics[0].Lyrics : "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Accessing files from a UWP application outside a select number folders requires additional permissions.

As you've pointed out, you've added the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability to your app manifest, which should allow access to any file that the end-user has access to.

The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability still requires the end-user to authorize the application. The end-user is usually prompted to do this if `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is specified and the permission has not yet been granted, however, in some cases, this is [broken](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/35781934-no-user-consent-prompt-on-first-run-of-broadfilesy). So you could check that the application has the required permissions, via the "Advanced Settings" link to your app under the Windows "Apps & settings" settings page.

If you're hardcoding the path, you could try letting the end-user pick the file using `FileOpenPicker` instead, to see if that makes a difference.

There is further information on file access permissions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: The File System toggle button for the app is on, but I still got permission denied.

Comment: I am not hardcoding the path. I am allowing user to see the lyrics when any music file is being played.

Comment: Can you post the code where the error is occurring and the full error you are receiving?

Comment: My code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Models/Music.cs) in the `GetLyrics` commented area. The exception is `System.UnauthorizedAccessException:“Access to the path 'C:\Users\Seaky\Desktop\Media\Music\Justin Bieber\Baby.mp3' is denied.”
`